# Events not firing in Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I have been searching high and low for an answer on this and I am completly dumbfounded.

I am implementing simple click and page tracking in my Android app using GA, running this through GTM. All my "Screens" are visible in realtime in GA but I can't get "Events" to appear at all.

Well actually I can but the behaviour seems very bizarre. If I do not include a "Label" and a "Value" I can see the events appear. However if I add them (either as just a constant or a data layer variable) all events stop. I have confirmed the variables I want in "Label" and "Value" are coming through as I made a container with those values as "Category" and "Action" and could see them as expected in real time.

This leads me to think the app side implementation is perfectly fine but there is an issue with my tag in GTM. (Obviously not the Trigger as that too works when expected).

Ideally I would like to do something like this (the variables are data layer variables):

[image: Ideal look]

But this doesn't work. I see no Events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Event Value should be a number, not a string. Shuffle the fields, for example - Action -  Click on: {{GTM - Click Target}}, Label - {{GTM - Click Value}}, and leave the value empty, this will fix your problem.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks! I didn't see anywhere that Value had to be a number, I never would have caught that

Comment: It is written in a field reference list: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Comment: So bad of google for not mentioning this on TAG configuration screen. There is no way for someone to find out from GTM docs. I wasted 2 days figuring out whats wrong. Thanks for saving me from wasting more time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have correctly setted up Click listener.

Enable when defines when is listener available and where is applied to the all DOM elements.

Fire ON defines conditions, so in your case it could be **{{event}} equals gtm.click** or **{{event}} equals gtm.linkClick** .

This is the most common pitfall when setting listeners

Comment: in GTM V2 there is no need of setting a click listener, they are automatically added by GTM itself.

Comment: that's true, but if you want to attach any event on it, you have to specify "Fire On" condition.

Comment: this is also true, but the OP says he see the event in real time if he don't use his variables, so it seems his trigger works fine, and he have problems with the variables itself.

Comment: ok, you're right! What makes me confused a little is statement, that Label and Value are DataLayer variables, but in screenshot there is a GTM Click -> So your Answer seems to be correct. +1 for you

Comment: Yeah I was using constants called {{GA - Whatever}} originally and there was a need to distingush. Calling them "GTM" now is confusing I agree

Comment: DLV - something is a nice option for the data layer variables naming, that's what i use most of the time